# How to find the vertices of irrigular ccsprite

Tags: iphone, box2d

**Vertices Problem**? I need to define collision of the ball with this tilted bar. My question is How can i find the vertices of the tilted bar (as shown in the image). I am making a `b2Polygone` to which i will added the 4 vertices of this tilted bar. Please someone give me a suggestion. Thanks.

The titled bar image is a ccsprite that i have added as user data to a static body. The position of the titled bar is  `ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/1.5)`.

**Image Link:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw4La.png

Comment: There is no image attached and try to use PhysicsEditor

Comment: Sorry for that. Now i have added the link to the image.

Comment: Ok, try http://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor and use the vertices helper. Also google Ray Wendlerlich with Physics Editor and that should lead you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks a lot.:) You are awesome. Going to check it out.